# How do I adapt this program in VBA so that the original temperature is placed in a cell next to the converted temperature?

Tags: excel, vba

This is my code... It keeps saying

```
SubConvertTemp()
Centigrade=MsgBox(Do you want to convert to centigrade?"),vbYesNo)
InputNumber=Val(InputBox("Enter a temperature for conversion?"))
If Centigradde= vbYes Then 
ConvertedTemp= ((9/5 *InputNumber)+32)
MsgBox((InputNumber & " degrees C converts to " & ConvertedTemp &" Degrees F."))
Else: ConvertedTemp=(5/9)*(InputNumber-32)
MsgBox(InputNumber & "degrees F converts to " & ConvertedTemp & "degrees C.")
Worksheets.("Sheet 1).Cells(InputNumber,ConvertedTemp).Offset(-1,0).Value="Name"
end sub
```

This code keeps saying syntax error? Not sure why

Comment: So many mistake in syntax.

Comment: What actually you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

A very small number of "syntax"typos:

```
Sub ConvertTemp()
    Centigrade = MsgBox("Do you want to convert to centigrade?", vbYesNo)
    InputNumber = Val(InputBox("Enter a temperature for conversion?"))
    If Centigradde = vbYes Then
        ConvertedTemp = ((9 / 5 * InputNumber) + 32)
        MsgBox ((InputNumber & " degrees C converts to " & ConvertedTemp & " Degrees F."))
    Else
        ConvertedTemp = (5 / 9) * (InputNumber - 32)
    End If
    MsgBox (InputNumber & " degrees F converts to " & ConvertedTemp & " degrees C.")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(InputNumber, ConvertedTemp).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Name"
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

A better version:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertTemp()

    Dim Centigrade As String, InputNumber As Variant, ConvertedTemp As Double

    Centigrade = MsgBox("Do you want to convert to centigrade?", vbYesNo)
    InputNumber = Val(InputBox("Enter a temperature for conversion?"))
    If Centigrade = vbYes Then
        ConvertedTemp = ((9 / 5 * InputNumber) + 32)
        MsgBox ((InputNumber & " degrees C converts to " & ConvertedTemp & " Degrees F."))
    Else
        ConvertedTemp = (5 / 9) * (InputNumber - 32)
    End If
    MsgBox (InputNumber & " degrees F converts to " & ConvertedTemp & " degrees C.")
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(InputNumber, ConvertedTemp).Offset(-1, 0).Value = "Name"
End Sub
```